# ggplot y-axis scale and scale interval

Tags: r

I am trying to make a ggplot, but I am not sure how to chnage the y-axis intervals or show specific intervals on the y-axis. How do you make the y-axis of a ggplot go up by 40, with the min being 40 and the max being 200, but only showing 80, 120, and 160 on the y-axis.

This is the graph I am trying to make
[image]

This is the graph I have so far
[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Is5p.png)]

The colors do not need to be the same, but I do need the same Y-axis intervals, how to do add this to my existing plot?

This is the code I have so far:

```
dl %>% 
 ggplot(mapping = aes(x = name, y = hr, fill = type)) + 
 geom_violin(show.legend = TRUE, alpha = 0.4, colour = NA) + 
 geom_boxplot(show.legend = TRUE, alpha = 0.4) +  
 theme_bw() + 
 labs(title = "Performance on lie detector test" , 
      y = "Heart rate" , x = "Name of person")
```

I also need to have the legend in the same place (top left corner)

And if there are any other tips (like why by box plots aren't centered like in the example or why my violin cuts off, but in the example they do not), that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: check https://tidyverse.github.io/ggplot2-docs/reference/scale_continuous.html